# Async pipe - data is undefined when reassigned

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have 2 components, one fetches the data from external service, another one displays it.

First component's constructor:

```
  constructor( private deviceInfoApi: DeviceInfoApiService ) {
    this.devicesPromise = this.deviceInfoApi.getDevices(false, false, false);
    let tempDevicesPromise = this.deviceInfoApi.getDevices(false, true, false).then(
     result => {
      this.devicesPromise = tempDevicesPromise;
     }
    );
   }
```

And its template:

```
<app-devices-table [devices]="devicesPromise | async"></app-devices-table>
```

Here's what I do:

1. I fetch some data using getDevices(false,false,false) - this one brings less information than I require, but is faster and enough to display something
2. I fetch some data using getDevices(false,true,false) - due to second argument being true, it will give me more information, but it takes longer to get the response.

So I want to first display some basic information and when more detailed package gets to me, I replace it.

Second component's input:

```
  @Input() devices: Array<any>;
```

And its template:

```
<table class="ui inverted table loading">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Online</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let device of devices">
        <td>{{ device.Id }}</td>
        <td>{{ device.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ device.DeviceType }}</td>
        <td>{{ device.IsConnected }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The result is that first call to getDevices returns some result and it is correctly displayed. As soon as the second result arrives and my devicesPromise gets replaced, it breaks - no table is displayed.

I added ngOnChanges() to my second component (the one with table):

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('CHANGES');
    console.log(this.devices);
  }
```

I see that first getDevices() result works fine - console.log displays my devices. Second one displays "undefined".

Why is that happening? Isn't it possible to update an Input with async pipe?
I'm sure the second call to getDevices() returns the right data, because I console.logged it in the first component's code and it was fine. Only second component sees it as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was simple, I changed the constructor of first argument to this:

```
  constructor( private deviceInfoApi: DeviceInfoApiService ) {
    this.devicesPromise = this.deviceInfoApi.getDevices(false, false, false);
    let tempDevicesPromise = this.deviceInfoApi.getDevices(false, true, false);
    tempDevicesPromise.then(
     result => {
      this.devicesPromise = tempDevicesPromise;
     }
    );
   }
```

I'm not sure why it helped, but it works now.